Excel VBA Macro Developed in Windows Convert for Mac
I'm trying to run VBA developed in Windows to work in Mac. This particular section is supposed to create document but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone please let me know what this section does?
            thisFileName = "Mactintosh HD:Library:FUPLOAD_TEMP:" & sFileName & ".txt"
            
            Open thisFileName For Append As #1
            Print #1, sText
            Close #1
            MsgBox (thisFileName)



For reference, here is the documentation for the Open statement, Print statement, and Close statement.

I have not tried it but just from reading it ... it opens a text file in "Mactintosh HD:Library:FUPLOAD_TEMP:" called whatever value is in sFileName with a .txt extension. It then appends some text from a variable sText then it closes the file. It then displays a message showing the name of the file it just opened. Possibly it is logging some event to a file.
